# Excel VBA check and display number of file in folder

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following module to check the number of files contained in a folder and display a messagebox with the with the number of files:

```
Sub CheckFiles(strDir As String, strType As String)

    Dim file As Variant, i As Integer
    strDir = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Source\"

    If Right(strDir, 1) <> "\" Then strDir = strDir & "\"
    file = Dir(strDir & strType)
    While (file <> "")
        i = i + 1
        file = Dir
    Wend
    MsgBox i
End Sub
```

Files to look for (in separate module):

```
   Call CheckFiles("", "File1*.xlsx")
    Call CheckFiles("", "File2*.xlsx")
```

What I want to do is to only display messagebox if the number of files for File1 is not excaly 3 and the number of files for File2 is not excaly 2. This is what I'm having trouble doing? How can this be acheived?

Comment: Add the number as a third parameter of the sub. Also, `If Right(strDir, 1) <> "\" Then strDir = strDir & "\"` is unnecessary, since you already have an ending backslash from `strDir = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Source\"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the `ChckNum` as Third Parameter in the Subject and pass it in the Call Statement

**Try:**

```
Sub CheckFiles(strDir As String, strType As String, chknum As Integer)

    Dim file As Variant, i As Integer
    strDir = ThisWorkbook.path & "\Source\"

    If Right(strDir, 1) <> "\" Then strDir = strDir & "\"
    file = Dir(strDir & strType)
    While (file <> "")
        i = i + 1
        file = Dir
    Wend

    If i <> chknum Then MsgBox i


End Sub
```

And

```
  Call CheckFiles("", "File1*.xlsx", 3)
  Call CheckFiles("", "File2*.xlsx", 2)
```